# Bookmark in TeXnicCenter 2 alpha3

Tags: texniccenter

Is there any way to put a marker in the source so that one can come back to it later? I have a long article and would like to edit it at some places and finding those places is time-consuming. I am using TeXnicCenter 2 alpha3.

(As similar question has been posted on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12296))

Comment: Please include all information relevant for your question here in this site. What do you mean with "mark"?

Comment: I mean tagging. I need to make some changes at certain places later in the text, @doncherry

Comment: As an alternative to using bookmarks, have you considered splitting up the article into several files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TeXnicCenter Help](http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/editor.html#editor-keyboard-shortcuts) mentions:

> Create or delete a bookmark: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   Go to next bookmark: <kbd>F2</kbd>

and

> Create or delete a bookmark: Click on the left-most margin.

I don't think these will remain if you close and re-open the document, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: TC 2 alpha 4 has a Bookmark pane (View/Tool Windows/Bookmarks) which shows all of them. Bookmarks can also be set by clicking the narrow gray bar/area left of the code, leaving a blue rectangle to indicate their position. Bookmarks do persist when a project is closed/reopened.